# static final object changes identity

Tags: dart, final

I have a browser application written in Dart. I noticed a strange error appearing where my StageXL ResourceManager was missing the resources that it previously had. After debugging the program for a while I ended up with this situation:

In global.dart:

```
class Global {
    static final ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager();
}
```

In main function:

```
var resources = Global.resourceManager;
resources.addBitmapData("Player", "images/player_base.png");
await resources.load();
print("in main: ${identityHashCode(Global.resourceManager)} = "
    " ${Global.resourceManager.resources}, isolate: ${identityHashCode(
    Isolate.current)}");
```

In another function where I need to access the resource afterwards:

```
print("elsewhere: ${identityHashCode(Global.resourceManager)} = "
    " ${Global.resourceManager.resources}, isolate: ${identityHashCode(
    Isolate.current)}");
```

Expected output (identityHashCodes match and so do the object contents):

```
in main: 12345678 = [ResourceManagerResource [kind=BitmapData, name=Player, 
    url = images/player_base.png]], isolate: 09876543
elsewhere: 12345678 = [ResourceManagerResource [kind=BitmapData, 
    name=Player, url = images/player_base.png]], isolate: 09876543
```

Actual output (note the identityHashCode mismatch):

```
in main: 516570559 = [ResourceManagerResource 
    [kind=BitmapData, name=Player, url = images/player_base.png]],
    isolate: 843028171
elsewhere: 419835243 = [], isolate: 843028171
```

I thought this may have something to do with running in a different isolate (not familiar with them) but as you can see, the current isolates identityHashCodes match.

Comment: Not soure what the question is. `Global.resourceManager` us final, `Global.resourceManager.resources` can still change.

Comment: Notice that the Global.resourceManager also changes its *identity*, as shown by the identityHashCode. The 'resourceManager.resources' changing is actually irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is surprising. My best guess is that you are importing the same library twice, using different URIs. The fact that one of your files is a "main" file supports this, since its a common mistake to specify the main file on the command line as a file and have it import a package library using a relative reference.

Is your "main" file in a package `lib` directory, and does it import the resource file using a relative path? If so, try changing that import to a `package:packageName/thepath` URI instead and see if it changes anything.

(My personal recommendation is to never have a Dart library URL that contains `lib`, whether in an import/export or on the command line. Always use a `package:` URI in that case instead.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I can't get to my code ATM, but I'll get back to you with my results as soon as I can.

Comment: Well, turns out this was the problem. I can't express how much time you've saved for me! Fixing this also fixed 3 other random bugs I had! Someone had mentioned that "package" imports are bad for dart2js compiler, that's why I used them everywhere!. Is this issue worth reporting to the Dart team? Seems like it should work regardless of the import method.

Comment: It's a well known issue to the Dart team. The Dart language specification identifiers libraries with the URI they are imported with. That works great to avoid duplicate libraries as long as you don't accidentally import a package library with a non-`package:` URI. That does happen occasionally, though, especially with a `main` file in a package that accesses the real package libraries with a relative import. It's not easy to detect because you can't always see if a file is intended as a "main" file, but I think we could do better in heuristically detecting issues like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was wondering why my Singleton is not working!